# WiX remove compont and componentRef of file

Tags: xml, xslt, wix

Using WiX 3.10:

I used the vdproj to WiX converter tool as we have several vdproj projects that needed to be updated in a hurry and didn't have time to do them all manually from scratch.  In the vdproj projects we excluded the .config files by using the exclude filter *.config, however, this did not translate when the projects were converted to WiX.  So I am left with attempting to remove them via the XSLT output.

I have seen several posts on how to do this, however, the ComponentRef piece does not get removed, only the Component.  My XSLT is rusty at best and here is what I added to the XSLT that does the transform for the project output.

```
.......

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:key name="config-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.config')]" use="@Id" />  
<xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('config-search', @Id)]" />
<xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('config-search', @Id)]"/>

.......
```

This is what I start with

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="SearchSync.Binaries">
      <Component Id="com_2DDFB814_CA3F_4E1F_8819_2249CB4C1377" Guid="{D07C7189-EFC9-4BA7-8E2F-9287333F2B4C}" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
                <File Id="_2DDFB814_CA3F_4E1F_8819_2249CB4C1377" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" KeyPath="yes" ReadOnly="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Source="$(var.SearchSync.TargetDir)\SearchSync.exe" />
            </Component>
      <Component Id="cmpE461B5F48229E9C8A0658DFAEF00FE18" Guid="{9B5BACCF-CCED-4649-AA82-1610C3414650}" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
                <File Id="fil441B326900F5FE7FF5BEA4BEEACF255C" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" KeyPath="yes" ReadOnly="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Source="$(var.SearchSync.TargetDir)\SearchSync.exe.config" />
            </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SearchSync.Binaries">
<ComponentRef Id="com_2DDFB814_CA3F_4E1F_8819_2249CB4C1377" />
<ComponentRef Id="cmpE461B5F48229E9C8A0658DFAEF00FE18" />
</ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

And this is what I end up with.  The Component is removed, but the ComponentRef is not.  The ID's of the Component and ComponentRef match.  How do I remove the corresponding ComponentRef?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="SearchSync.Binaries">
      <Component Id="com_2DDFB814_CA3F_4E1F_8819_2249CB4C1377" Guid="{D07C7189-EFC9-4BA7-8E2F-9287333F2B4C}" Permanent="no" SharedDllRefCount="no" Transitive="no">
                <File Id="_2DDFB814_CA3F_4E1F_8819_2249CB4C1377" DiskId="1" Hidden="no" KeyPath="yes" ReadOnly="no" System="no" Vital="yes" Source="$(var.SearchSync.TargetDir)\SearchSync.exe" />
            </Component>

    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="SearchSync.Binaries">
<ComponentRef Id="com_2DDFB814_CA3F_4E1F_8819_2249CB4C1377" />
<ComponentRef Id="cmpE461B5F48229E9C8A0658DFAEF00FE18" />
</ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Comment: I found this post on SO. But attempting either solution didn't work as well. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20265628/removing-a-self-referencing-node-in-xml-using-xsl

Comment: The XSLT fragments you have shown should do the trick. See http://xsltransform.net/jyRYYig/1. Do you have any other templates in your XSLT though? For example, other templates that match `wix:ComponentRef` elements?

Comment: Not exactly, there were templates to wix:ComponentGroup though and searches for wix:ComponentRef therein, however, moving the pieces that do the removal to the bottom of the xslt file, removed everything as needed. - Thanks for the tip which helped me find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

While the comment from Tim C proved helpful and ultimately the XSLT was syntactically correct and did it's job when only using the bits provided, even in Visual Studio it did this.  However, when applying the solution to the entire project it still failed to remove the ComponentRef of the Project.Binaries portion of the .wxs output.

So this the solution that finally worked was to add an XSLT file with just the remove code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <!-- Copy all attributes and elements to the output. -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <!-- Remove all .config files from the install of the msi 
   This xslt is called from the heat.exe -t switch command from the .wixproj file. 
   Unload the wixproj file and then edit to modify or remove the -t switch if .config files are to be included. -->
  <xsl:key name="config-search" match="wix:Component[contains(wix:File/@Source, '.config')]" use="@Id" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:Component[key('config-search', @Id)]" />
  <xsl:template match="wix:ComponentRef[key('config-search', @Id)]" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

After that unload and edit the .wixproj file in Visual Studio.  Find the Exec Command that does the heat.exe for your project.  Add the -t switch to your command line with the location to the xslt file you made.

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(Wix)Bin\heat.exe&quot; .... -t &quot;XSLT\XslRemoveConfig.xslt&quot;  ... " />
```

That's it, you don't have to do anything else and all references to your .config files will be removed and thus they will not be installed when the .msi is ran.